# how to pass dictionary from one activity to another activity via intent in android

Tags: android

I have a dictionary that I need to pass via the Intent to another Activity via the onclick method.How to put dictionray in intent and how to get it from intent in another activity.

Comment: 1) What type of object is the dictionary (can you post the code?) 2) Why do you need to pass it (you could let it be a singleton object that both Activities access directly 3) What have you tried so far?

Comment: dicitonray is type of object like below                     Dictionary<Object, ArrayList<Object>> userListDictionary = new Hashtable<Object, ArrayList<Object>>(); how to pass it? how to use pracelable or serializable?

Answer (score 3):

You should implement dictionary to Parcelable interface. It also has higher performance than Serializable.

Implementing Parcelable will help you to send and receive custom objects via intents.

The following links will help you how to implement Parcelable:

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/pass-complex-object-structure-to-intent/

Comment: dicitonray is type of object like below Dictionary<Object, ArrayList<Object>> userListDictionary = new Hashtable<Object, ArrayList<Object>>(); how to pass it? how to use pracelable or serializable?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the complexities involved in sending data via intents, for a custom data-structure, give a try to another, much easier approach:

The following steps with code will guide you how it works.

First : **CREATE A BRIDGE**

Create a class named Bridge as follows:

```
class Bridge
{
    private Bridge{
    }

    static Bridge obj = null;
    public static Bridge instance()
    {
         if (obj == null) 
         obj = new Bridge();
         return obj;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> aList; // put your data structure here

 }
```

Second : **SEND DATA**

In the Activity.java file from where you want to send data, put this code. This is the part where you initialize the data structure of Bridge class

```
ArrayList<String> sendList = new ArrayList<String>();
Bridge.instance().aList = sendList; // where sendList is the data structure that contains your data
```

Third : **RECEIVE DATA**

Receive the data like this in your Activity.java file

```
ArrayList<String> receiveList = new ArrayList<String>();
receiveList = Bridge.instance().alList;
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary needs to be Serializable.

You can pass it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putSerializable(key, dictionary);
intent.putExtras(extras);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: dicitonray is type of object like below Dictionary<Object, ArrayList<Object>> userListDictionary = new Hashtable<Object, ArrayList<Object>>(); how to pass it? how to use pracelable or serializable?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach to access objects across Activities and Fragments:

```
public class MySharedObject {

    // add shared data fields here

    private static MySharedObject instance;
    private Context context;

    // only add Context if you need it
    public static MySharedObject getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance != null) {
            instance.context = context; // update to context from caller
            return instance;
        }

        return instance = new MySharedObject(context); 
    }

    private MySharedObject(Context context) { // private constructor
        this.context = context;

        // do any initial loading needed
        // this constructor will only be called at the first getInstance call

    }

    ...

}
```

Now in any Activity or Fragment call:

```
// this = getActivity() if inside Fragment
MySharedObject myObject = MySharedObject.getInstance(this);
```

To get the shared data.

As for your dictionary you simply add the userListDictionary field and a getter method. The call could then look something like:

```
Dictionary<Object, ArrayList<Object>> userListDictionary = SharedDictionary.getInstance(this).getUserListDictionary();
```